# Updating JSON tags format using in perl

Tags: xml, json, perl, hash

I have a perl code which is generating JSON from an XML file. Everything is working fine and i am getting the conversion done properly.

So current code is generating the JSON from XML generically that is JSON has all of its tags and their structure same as present in the XML file.

but i want JSON tags to have some specific format always irrespective of the input xml.

For example here is the code snippet for perl code, input XML, generically generated JSON and  expected JSON.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Person SchemaVersion="1.0.8">
    <personalData>
        <workList>
            <file>
                 "fileName": "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz",
            </file>
        </workList>
    </personalData>
</Person>
```

Perl code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings FATAL => qw( all );
 use Data::Dumper;

 use JSON;

    # Create the object of XML Simple
    my $xmlSimple = new XML::Simple(KeepRoot   => 1);

    # Load the xml file in object
    my $dataXML = eval { $xmlSimple->XMLin(Input_XML_File_Path)};

    # use encode json function to convert xml object in json.
    my $jsonString = encode_json($dataXML);

    print $jsonString;
```

Current Output JSON:

```
{
    "Person":{

       "personalData": {
          "workList": {
             "file":{
                "fileName": "/usr/temp/ABC.txt"
               }
           },
       }
    }
 }
```

New output to generate:

```
{
    "Person":{

       "personalData": {
          "workList": {
             "file":[
                 { "fileName": "/usr/temp/ABC.txt" }
              ]
           },
         "eventList": {
            "event": [
                 {}
             ]
          }
        }
      }   
    }
```

Difference between current JSON output generated to what needs to be generated:

1> Tag file needs to be pursued as an array here instead of a normal tag.
This is stupid since input tag has just one value so no point having as array but next step of process is expecting the tag as nested so need to make that change.

```
    "file":[
        { "fileName": "/usr/temp/ABC.txt" }
      ]
```

INSTEAD of following:

```
    "file":{
        "fileName": "/usr/temp/ABC.txt"
      }
```

2> Tag Eventlist is not present in the input xml file so need to hard code, so that output JSON has always that tag inside it. ( next step of process needs that ).

let me know if any questions.

NOTE: i am able to add new tag into JSON but not in the way i wanted.

```
 my $tempHash = decode_json($jsonString );
 # adding the new key-value pair into the hash map
 $tempHash->{'Person'}->{'PersonalData'}->{'workList'}->{$key} = $val;
 # encoding the hash map back into JSON
 my $jsonWithKey =  encode_json($tempHash);
```

Comment: XML data can't map uniquely to a JSON data structure, and your mission is bound to fail unless you have a special verification on the XML data that can be accepted. This is exactly the same problem that [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple) suffered, and has now had to bow out

Comment: You seem to have three unrelated questions. Please post unrelated questions in unrelated post

Comment: @ikegami: you can ignore third question but first two are related to each other or at least same logic will be used. to your first question file tag will be pursuade as : "file":[ {"fileName": "/usr/temp/ABC.txt"} ]

Comment: updated the question as well.

Comment: @user1188611: But *you can't express XML data in simple JSON*. Really!

Comment: @Borodin: i am having similar questions, but this modification need to be done in order to align to the next step of process. That next step cant be modified. I completely agree to what you are saying here

Comment: Question 1 (*How do I change `{ fileName = >"/usr/temp/ABC.txt" }` to `[ { fileName = >"/usr/temp/ABC.txt" } ]`?*) is unrelated to question 2 (*How do I add add a hash element with value `{ event => [ {} ] }` to a hash?*) because the problems are different and the solutions are different. They don't overlap at all.

Comment: Don't add new questions to existing questions.

Comment: posted the query in a separate question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398517/modifying-data-structure-that-will-be-encoded-using-json-in-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change JSON; you can change the data structure that will be encoded using JSON. Since this is a Perl question, I shall use Perl syntax to describe those structures rather than JSON. This should make the solutions to your question dead obvious.

1. Your asking how to change

   ```
   { fileName => "/usr/temp/ABC.txt" }
   ```

   to

   ```
   [ { fileName => "/usr/temp/ABC.txt" } ]
   ```

   It's simply

   ```
   $var = [ $var ];
   ```

   In context, that's

   ```
   $data->{Person}{personalData}{workList}{file} =
      [ $data->{Person}{personalData}{workList}{file} ];
   ```
2. You're asking how to change

   ```
   { }
   ```

   to

   ```
   { eventList => { event => [ { } ] } }
   ```

   Adding an element to a referenced hash is simply

   ```
   $hash_ref->{$key} = $value;
   ```

   In context, that's

   ```
   $data->{Person}{eventList} = { event => [ { } ] };
   ```