# Modifying data structure that will be encoded using JSON in perl

Tags: json, perl

I have a JSON whcih i am trying to modify using perl code.

```
{
    "Person":{

       "personalData": {
          "workList": {
              "file":{ 
                  "fileName": "/usr/temp/ABC.txt" }
                },
            }
         }
       }   
    }
```

I need to convert the above JSON into something like this:

```
{
    "Person":{

       "personalData": {
          "workList": {
              "directoryList":{
                   "directory":[
                       "file":{ 
                           "fileName": "/usr/temp/ABC.txt" }
                          }
                     ]
                }
            }
         }
       }   
    }
```

Can someone give some example of doing this in perl.

Comment: simple: decode the json into a native perl structure, manipulate that structure, then re-encode to json.

Comment: @MarcB: i know how i can insert a new tag within an existing tag in perl data structure. But here in this particular case i need to overwrite an existing structure  ( tag fileName ) and have it nested (two levels down ) in hierarchy rooted to same parent. ( workList ).   that is worklist -> fileName now becomes worklist->directoryList->directory->filename.

Comment: let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: I would recommend reading [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) (the official Perl data structures cookbook) and the [Data Structures](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/perl/excerpts/9780596000271/data-structures.html) chapter from Programming Perl. They will help you understand how to manipulate any data structure, no matter how nested, so you don't have to keep learning things via the blind copy-paste method.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: thanks for the suggestion, i was actually able to figure out by myself. But i will make sure i read the cookBook and Data structure at least to learn perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data->{Person}{personalData}{workList}{directoryList}{directory} =
    [ delete $data->{Person}{personalData}{workList}{file} ];
```

Or more concisely,

```
$tmp = $data->{Person}{personalData}{workList};
$tmp->{directoryList}{directory} = [ delete $tmp->{file} ];
```

For an explanation of how this works see: [How to replace a Perl hash key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490356/how-to-replace-a-perl-hash-key)

Comment: @user1188611 and mob Can you explain a bit?  I'll ++ you if you do ;-) Does `delete` both remove the value from the `$data` hash ***and*** return it?  I take it  that by doing this inside an anonymous array constructor (`[ ]`) the hash entry can be added back in the new location.

Comment: @G. Cito. Yes, see the related link above.

Comment: Thanks since your answer is accepted for the other question I think it stays at the top of the page.  I will  edit into your response :-)